# How to set UTF-8 for the parsed xml file using SAX Parser in android

Tags: android, utf-8, saxparser

I am parsing an XML file obtained from the remote server,which consists of some different fonts using `SAX Parser` and I want to set UTF-8 to this.How can I set?

#### Code is:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                   /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(myURL);
        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler )*/
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Waiting for the help from SO,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to parse xml response.

Xml.parse(in, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, contentHandler);

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the encoding in your InputSource: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html

It has got a method `setEncoding(String encoding)` - set that to "UTF8"